# Sum convergence test problem.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I’ve come across this sum, and I need to test the convergence, but I really have no idea how to get started.
This is the sum:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^{\sqrt{6}+1}+n+5}{n^{\sqrt6+2}+2n+10}
$$
Can you give me some tips? Thanks!.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** $\left(\dfrac{n^{\sqrt{6}+1}+n+5}{n^{\sqrt6+2}+2n+10}\right)_{n\in \mathbb N}\sim _\infty\left(\dfrac{n^{\sqrt{6}+1}}{n^{\sqrt6+2}}\right)_{n\in \mathbb N}=\,?$

Comment: I get it, with comparision test my sum does not converge. Thank you.

Comment: @user137209 No need to hurry in accepting my answer. Maybe you like another one better.

Answer (score 6):

For $n\ge1$,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{n^{\sqrt{6}+1}+n+5}{n^{\sqrt6+2}+2n+10}
&=\frac1n\frac{1+n^{-\sqrt6}+5n^{-\sqrt6-1}}{1+2n^{-\sqrt6-1}+10n^{-\sqrt6-2}}\\
&\ge\frac1n\cdot\frac7{13}
\end{align}
$$